# Instillation error for woocommerce plugin on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I tried installing the woocommerce plugin but every time I install it I get this error:

Installation failed: Could not copy file. woocommerce/vendor/symfony/css-selector/XPath/TranslatorInterface.php

any tips or help? Thanks, have a good day.

Comment: You need to provide more information, what is the plugin? Did you download it from the wordpress plugins repository or from a third party website? Have you contacted the author of the plugin re: the issue? Is it compatible with your version of wordpress/woocommerce?

Answer (score 0):

Considering your problem, i think you were trying to download a plugin from the wordpress plugin interface. More information would be valued but you can try

1. Check Storage
2. Uninstall and reinstall
3. (Quite likely), Check the files/directory permission setting.